# My dual-core Celeron-4205 is only showing 1 core. What happened to the other core?

Tags: windows, boot, cpu, core

Where Is My Another Cores My One Core Is Missing Please Resolve My Issue Please Reply Me Soon

[image: system configuration screenshot]

Comment: Boot options are not the place to look for core count. Use CPU-Z or the Performance tab of the task manager. There's a core count under the CPU graph.

Answer (score 4):

This setting is super confusing.

You've checked the *Number of processors* checkbox, selected *1* and rebooted. Now Windows doesn't know that the 2nd core exists, because it's disabled.

The trick is to **uncheck** *Number of processors*, then reboot. This will disable core limiting. Windows will boot with all cores enabled.